# Can I have one recycleview that loads different datasets

Tags: java, android

I am working on mobile app which is for books.

I have recyclerview that has all categories - Romance, History etc.This RV is taking the data from Firebase.

What I want to do is following:

When the user clicks on Romance for example, a new activity needs to be opened. In that activity I want to have one RV loading the data-set with all books from that type.

Then, If the user opens History I want that data-set to be loaded into the same RV.

I want to avoid code repeating and what I am asking is - can I have 1 class with If statements that can handle the user choice and load the data-sets into one RV?

Would you be able to tell me how, if its possible?

Thank you !

Edit: Here is my code. What I did so far is Adapter, GetAndSet class, 2 Activities. To show categories into one RV I use 1 adapter and 1 GetAndSet class,1 XML file. I created 2 separate classes for romance and Comedy and inside them I do the connection to firebase.
Adapter:

public class CategoriesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
Context mContext;
List<Categories> mData;

public CategoriesAdapter(Context mContext, List<Categories> mData) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mData = mData;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View row = LayoutInflater.from( mContext ).inflate( R.layout.row_attractions, parent, false );

    return new MyViewHolder( row );
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.DesName.setText( mData.get( position ).getName() );
    Glide.with( mContext ).load( mData.get( position ).getImage() ).into( holder.DesImage );
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView DesName;
    ImageView DesImage;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super( itemView );

        itemView.setClickable( true );
        mContext = itemView.getContext();

        DesName = itemView.findViewById( R.id.DesName );
        DesImage = itemView.findViewById( R.id.DesImage );
        DesImage.setOnClickListener( this );
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        final Intent intent;
        Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(),"Test",Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        switch (getAdapterPosition()) {
            case 0:
                intent = new Intent( mContext, Romance.class );
                break;

             case 1:
                intent = new Intent( mContext, Comedy.class );
              break;

            // case 2:
            //     intent = new Intent( mContext, RegentsPark.class );
            //  break;

            default:
                intent = new Intent( mContext, Home.class );
                break;
        }
        mContext.startActivity( intent );
    }

}
```

}

Romance class (Same as Comedy class,except the line with Firebase where I reffer to the dataset:

```
public class Romance extends AppCompatActivity {


RecyclerView categoriesRecyclerView ;
CategoriesAdapter categoriesAdapter  ;
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
DatabaseReference databaseReference ;
List<Categories> categoriesList;

private EditText mSearchField;
private ImageButton mSearchBtn;

private RecyclerView mResultList;

private DatabaseReference mUserDatabase;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_romance);


    categoriesRecyclerView  = findViewById(R.id.BookRV);
    categoriesRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(Romance.this));
    categoriesRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("ListParks");

   // mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Categories");


    mSearchField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_field);
    mSearchBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.search_btn);

    mResultList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.result_list);
    mResultList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mResultList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    mSearchBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String searchText = mSearchField.getText().toString();

            firebaseUserSearch(searchText);

        }
    });

}

private void firebaseUserSearch(String searchText) {

    Toast.makeText(Romance.this, "Started Search", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Query firebaseSearchQuery = mUserDatabase.orderByChild("name").startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + "\uf8ff");

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UsersViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UsersViewHolder>(

            Users.class,
            R.layout.list_layout,
            UsersViewHolder.class,
            firebaseSearchQuery

    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(UsersViewHolder viewHolder, Users model, int position) {


            viewHolder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(), model.getName(), model.getImage());

        }
    };

    mResultList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

}


// View Holder Class

public static class UsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View mView;

    public UsersViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;

    }

    public void setDetails(Context ctx, String userName, String userImage){

        TextView user_name = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.name_text);
        ImageView user_image = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);


        user_name.setText(userName);

        Glide.with(ctx).load(userImage).into(user_image);


    }




}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();


    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            categoriesList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot catsnap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                Categories post = catsnap.getValue(Categories.class);
                categoriesList.add(post) ;
            }
            //set Adapter
            categoriesAdapter = new CategoriesAdapter(Romance.this,categoriesList);
            categoriesRecyclerView.setAdapter(categoriesAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
}
```

Can I avoid creating different classes for each type of books?

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. what you're describing, definitely sounds possible, but it's way easier for us to help when you post what you've tried so far. consider trying something out and then asking here when you get stuck on something specific

Comment: You can just set a new data set, then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Just added  my code, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know what category the user selected on the first RecyclerView:

Pass the category name/identifier to the activity you want to open when user clicks on the RecyclerView item. And then from the second activity get your data-set object according to the category you got from the previous activity and pass it to the adapter.

You can make a custom RecyclerView.Adapter.
Here is a good example:

[Android Developers Documentation Example](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview#Adapter)

When the adapter is initiated, you pass the data-set. This is the constructor of your custom RecyclerView.Adapter class:

```
public MyAdapter(String[] myDataset) {
    mDataset = myDataset;
}
```

So every time you create the activity which is listing the books, you can create new RecyclerView.Adapter instance passing your data-set.

Put this somewhere in your onCreate method of the activity:

```
MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(myDataset);
recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

When your activity is created, your RecyclerView will be loaded with the new data-set you provided the RecyclerView.Adapter with.

**P.S.**
If you are actually resuming the activity and have never destroyed it and want to change the adapter of already existing RecyclerView and refresh new items, you can do this in your onResume method

```
MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(myDataset);
recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Another way would be, again, if you are resuming (not creating) the activity and really don't want to create new Adapter and set it every time the activity resumes, then you will have to ***edit*** manually the data-set object you passed earlier to your custom adapter and call:

```
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

By saying ***edit*** I don't mean reassigning the variable! If you reassign the variable with another object, the adapter will loose the reference to that object and it will not work.